# How to print “Folder” for TRUE and “File” for FALSE in final output .csv file while run command @isdir

Tags: cmd

I have .bat file with the following code

```
forfiles /S /C "cmd /c echo @path,@IsDir" >> "%dpath%" 2>&1.
```

The resultant .csv file reports "True" for Directory(folders) and "False" for all non directories(file).

I would like the output to report "Folder" instead of "True", and "File" instead of "False".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to add an IF statement, but the more efficient solution is to define variables for TRUE and FALSE and let variable expansion produce the result.

```
setlocal
set "true=Folder"
set "false=File"
forfiles /S /C "cmd /c echo @path,%%@IsDir"%%>> "%dpath%" 2>&1.
```